# Get posts by list of post IDs ordered by those IDs?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, array, id

I am going to make a "favourite" posts box, but the article id's are stored in another DB so I only get an array of IDs (which **are** relevant to the WP DB).

I think it could be done with `get_posts()` or simply just with `WP_Query`, however as I am surfing through the codex I cant find solution to my problem - you can obviously select posts by multiple tags, authors,... but I cant find something similar for just IDs.

I wouldnt even mind if the posts werent ordered. Mainly I just want to get a bunch of posts in one (WP)Query providing only posts' ids.

Any Ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `post__in` as a parameter in your `WP_Query`, like:

```
$favourite_posts = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'post__in' => array( 111, 222, 333 ),
        'orderby' => 'ID'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: It solves the main problem. However - one more question - How to order by the position of ids in provided array? You know like 'post__in' => array(8,1,4,2) would return posts in order like 8,1,4,2 - or is that by default with using post__in?

Comment: The custom order like 8,1,4,2, cannot be done with `WP_Query` by using `orderby` parameter, you have to select the posts first, then order them in PHP, maybe with a custom order function, something like that.

Comment: Another funny thing - if the post__in's array() is empty it returns all the posts

Comment: Yes, it did! I've encountered that before.

Comment: So to prevent extra posts I ended up with: `WP_Query(array( 'post__in' => $favourite_posts, 'cat' => 1, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 3  ))`

Answer (score 3):

#### To Maintain the Order as by Given IDs

Since 3.5 we have option called **orderby => post__in**

Preserve post ID order given in the post__in array (available since Version 3.5).

```
$ordered_posts = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'post__in' => array( 21, 5, 33 ),
        'orderby' => 'post__in'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Do you realize this makes **as many SQL queries as there are fetched posts?** :-) get_posts/WP_Query should loot them at once ...

Comment: You are right it is n+1 queries scenario. Thanks for the heads up, in my case it was for given three posts I wanted to show. But latest WP have another ordering built-in so I am going to update my answer with that. Thanks again for your kind feedback!

Comment: This is not what I wanted, but I will give this a +1 because it is an interesting way of abstractly doing custom order-ing :-) BTW: Be aware of queries*n, especially in WP stack, forums and other WP material this is often overlooked and causes trouble when used within more complex / larger websites :)